# Dynamic controls Handling Postsback caused by calendar and button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I am having some issues handling post-backs. I can't seem to get the right checkbox value. Been trying to figure this out but not able to. Appreciate all the help I can get.

I have a dynamic table, which creates check-boxes in 10 cells (representing hours), according to the number of objects in the database.

It is able to insert to datebase without problem if
  Load Page -> select date by clicking on Img Button -> generate dynamic table based on selected date -> check checkboxes -> add record.

However, problem occurs when I view multiple dates  (eg:)

Load Page -> select date by clicking on Img Button -> generate dynamic table based on selected date -> click Img Button -> Generate dynamic table ->

I have done the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData(); //generate dataset to construct table
        }
    }
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Calendar1.Visible = false;

        Table.Rows.Clear();
        LoadData();


    }
```

I've added Table.Rows.Clear(); on Calendar.SelectionChanged and Imagebutton click. If not, more than one table will appear. Eg: 1 for first date selection, 2nd one following below it from second date selection

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `!IsPostBack`

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
     LoadData(); //generate dataset to construct table
 }
```

This is the initial load. Once you postback - selected change - this should not load again. I assume the `LoadData()` creates the datatable or set therefore on postback loading it multiple times.

Comment: If I do that, the table will not load on button click, resulting in error as well. 
Not being able to add checkbox details into database